# Using JS to Change Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have a script I am using that will change a link from a regular link to a *mailto* link. The idea is most bad robots will not parse javascript thus is a bit better than putting the email address as is or spacing and spelling the *@* symbol.

The HTML should render as:

> Contact our Sales Manager by email.

The word email would be a link to the email. However with the JS code it renders as so:

> Contact our Sales Manager by email@email.com.

I would like the first sentence to be how the page renders.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Contact our Sales Manager by
   <a class="email" title="email/email.com" href=" ">email</a>.
</p>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {

  $('a.email').each(function(){

    var e = this.title.replace('/','@');

    $(this).text().replace('/','@');

    this.href=" ";

    this.href = 'mailto:' + e; $(this).text(e);

   });
});
```

How would I modify the script to leave the word email in there but create the link correctly?

Comment: I suggest you to read more about javascript and string manipulation

Comment: @pylover - I am learning JS and taking it step by step.

Comment: see my answer and jsfiddle example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/smLQ7/

To fix this, simply remove one part of the JavaScript so it is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.email').each(function(){
    var e = this.title.replace('/','@');
    $(this).text().replace('/','@');
    this.href=" ";
    this.href = 'mailto:' + e;
   });
});​
```

We have removed this code:

```
$(this).text(e);
```

It was responsible for replacing `email` with `email@email.com` in the page contents.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$(this).text(e)
```

by

```
$(this).text('email');
```

`text('some string')` replaces the content of the element by its argument. So in your case, the link's content was being replaced by the email address.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do it via JS then why bother putting the address in the tag at all?

Why not just try something like this on (document).ready()

```
var theaddress ="mailto:email@email.com"

$('a.email').attr('href',theaddress);
```

EDIT:

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/sMnrR/

Comment: I have thought of that but I use templates and I can stick the code in the template and then just add the class email and title to the specific email addresses. It seems convoluted I know but in my case it works better. Though I may use your example in other places. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If understand your problem, Here is solution:

```
$(function() {
  $('a.email').each(function(){

    var e = this.title.replace('/','@');
    $(this)
        .attr('href','mailto:' + e)
        .text(e.substr(0,e.indexOf("@")));
   });
});​
```

Take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptqTc/)